# How to write regular expression that will catch up following

Tags: regex, perl

```
ticket number: 6666
ticket number : 6666
ticket #6666
ticket # 6666
```

i tried this one `ticket[ \t]+(number|#)?[: \t]+([0-9]+)`
but it does not work for "ticket #6666"

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close; you want the colon/space to be optional.

```
ticket[ \t]+(number|#)?[: \t]*([0-9]+)
```

Comment: @KirillReva - Here at stackoverflow we thank you by accepting the best answer - so please click on check-mark below the number left next to this post (it will change color to green), if you want to thank you to #geekosaur.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `ticket[\s\t]+(number|#)[:\s\t]*([0-9]+)`

Also, if you don't already use it I would recommend http://regexpal.com/ to help you with your testing. It is a great resource to quickly see what is being matched by your expression.